# Furnace flames run for a minute then shut off

Tags: furnace, troubleshooting

I have a furnace (Model: NUGK050CF01) that has recently been experiencing some weird behavior. The furnace will come on (I can see the flames) and it will run for a little over a minute. Then the flames will go out for about 7 minutes, then the cycle repeats itself. The blower is on continuously while all of this happens.

I've done some research and this kind of behavior can be consistent with a dirty flame sensor or if the furnace isn't getting enough airflow. I have checked my air filter and it looks fine. I was unable to located the flame sensor and it looks like my unit does not have one. I've included some pictures.

[image: Furnace]

[image: Furnace model number]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. That's a pretty old unit; [this](http://www.utcccs-cdn.com/hvac/docs/1011/Public/0A/NUGK_SERVICE_MANUAL__PART_1_ICP_20983.pdf) and [this](http://www.utcccs-cdn.com/hvac/docs/1011/Public/09/NUGK_SERVICE_MANUAL_PART_2_ICP_20984.pdf) may be the service manual.

Comment: Are you certain there isn't an internal thermostat which shuts off the burner head when the local temperature gets too high? Any way to check on the output air temperature?

Comment: I agree with Carl, this sounds like a typical case of tripping the high limit (in other words, the furnace is overheating).  When you say the blower is on, are you talking about the fan which sends air throughout the house or the combustion air blower (large brown thing) directly below the burners?

Comment: Does the unit display any error codes?

Comment: Do you have a manometer and a multimeter?  If not, go get them.

Comment: When you say "*The blower is on continuously*". Do you mean the draft inducer (little blower connected to the exhaust pipe), or the **blower** (large device that blows air throughout the home)?

Comment: Thanks everyone @DanielGriscom how did you find the manual?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I can measure the output air temp when I get home

Comment: @ConnorBredin If I shut the unit off then start it back up, the combustion air blower (is that the same as a draft inducer?) comes on first and once the flames start then the main blower runs continuously.

Comment: @Tester101 I have a multimeter but not a manometer. The draft inducer kicks on first, then followed by the blower. Tonight I can check to see the order things come on and stay up, the the blower is what runs continuously. I don't think this unit has error codes (I didn't see any thing on the board that could display them)

Comment: If the blower is staying on, it might point to an open limit. When the burners shut down, use a multimeter to check the heat exchanger high limit and exhaust high limit, to see if either of them have opened.

Comment: I can check tonight to see if either are open. If it is a faulty sensor, can I short it?
Because my house is now 55F I've made a service call and the guy will be out tomorrow to check it out, hopefully if its something simple like a TC he can replace it right away. Either way I will update this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The high limit was indeed being reached. This was confirmed by watching the unit trip the high limit after the burners were turned on.

I had thought that the unit was getting enough air since my filter was new. It turned out that the secondary heat exchanger was packed full of matted dog hair and dust. I'll explain how I cleaned it.

1. Remove service panels, disconnect wires (orange stars), disconnect spark plug (pink star). Then remove the two screws marked with the blue stars to removed electrical box, gently set aside.
   [image: Furnace with service panels removed]
2. Disconnect the 3 wires attacked to the blower, be sure to note how they were connected, then remove the two screws that keep the blower from sliding out on the metal track (visible in the upper left). Then slide out blower.
   [image: Furnace blower]
3. Things should then look like this. The secondary heat exchanger is in the back and above the visible foil.
   [image: Furnace with blower removed]
4. This is what the heat exchanger looked like, and what it looked like after a bit of cleaning.
   [image: Filthy heat exchanger]
   [image: Cleaner heat exchanger]

I then vacuumed the rest of the heat exchanger as well as everything else to try and reduce future buildup. Everything is then put back in reverse order.

Thank you everyone for your help!